# Cargar valor de variable dentro de una function en otra function

Tags: java, android-studio, kotlin

Estoy haciendo un juego sencillo para aprender a programar para Android con Kotlin.
Temgo una activity(game) del juego y cuando encuentras un numero te lleva a otra atcivity(Finish), pasando dos informaciones, que están en OnCreate.

```
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)

    val iFinish = getIntent()
    val numbers: String = iFinish.getStringExtra("LEVEL_NUMBER")
    val plays: String = iFinish.getStringExtra("NUMBER_PLAYS")

    textViewNumPlays.text = plays
    textViewRandom.text = numbers
}
```

Luego tengo dos botones, uno que regresa para el Menu Princial, otro reinicia el juego con las mismas configuraciones anteriores, pero el que reinicia necesita de la val numbers y la function esta fuera del onCreate.

```
fun onButtonRestartClicked (view: View){
    val message1 = numbers.toString()
    val iRestart = Intent(this, GameActivity::class.java).apply {
        putExtra("EXTRA_MESSAGE", message1);
    }
    if (iRestart.resolveActivity(packageManager) != null) {
        startActivity(iRestart)
    }
}
```

Mi duda es como cargar este val numbers en una funcion fuera del onCreate?

Answer (score 0):

Descobri mi error
Añadi una variable global var numeros = 0, luego la actualize dentro de onCreate.

```
var numeros = 0

fun onButtonMenuClicked (view: View){
    val iMenu = Intent(this, StartActivity::class.java)

    if (iMenu.resolveActivity(packageManager) != null) {
        startActivity(iMenu)
    }
    this.finish()
}

fun onButtonRestartClicked (view: View){
    val message1 = numeros.toString()
    val iRestart = Intent(this, GameActivity::class.java).apply {
        putExtra("EXTRA_MESSAGE", message1);
    }
    if (iRestart.resolveActivity(packageManager) != null) {
        startActivity(iRestart)
    }
    this.finish()
}

val iFinish = getIntent()
val numbers: String = iFinish.getStringExtra("LEVEL_NUMBER")
val plays: String = iFinish.getStringExtra("NUMBER_PLAYS")

textViewNumPlays.text = plays
textViewRandom.text = numbers
numeros = numbers.toInt()
```